# shaking front end

Tags: hyundai, vibration, elantra

Hi I have a 2014 Hyundai Elantra. last week while driving home it started to shake at about 40 mph. then again at about 60. also shaking while turning corners. thoughtit might be the cv axel but after getting it look at the shop. they said all the suspension looked good. I was told that my tires were bad. so after getting new tires and having them balanced two times. I'm still having the same issues. if anybody has any ideas what I should look at help would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: The CV axel isn't really part of the suspension (unless I'm confused about what suspension is.) Your description does sound a lot like a CV axel, but it's equally possible that the tires are bad. If tires are badly out of balance, they will sometimes wear more on one side than the other. Balancing them will place the center of mass at the axel, but the outsides wouldn't necessarily all have the same radius from that point, thereby causing the shaking like you describe. Getting new tires should have solved that though. I'd recommend getting a second opinion on the CV axels from someone else.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did the shop inspect wheel bearings?

Comment: Are there some unusual sounds while driving?

Answer (score 0):

Shaking / vibrating can be caused by the following things:

- Tires (Uneven tire wear, improper wheel balance or wrong alignment)
- Suspension (Worn out ball joints, dampers, springs)
- Brakes (Uneven brake wear or uneven thickness in brake rotors)
- Engine and transmission mounts.
- Wheel bearings.

Since you had the suspension inspected and new wheels fitted, I'm suspecting either worn-out wheel bearings or worn-out engine or transmission mounts. Also you didn't mention anything brake related, so I don't think any brake parts are causing this issue.

I'd look at the engine and transmission mounts first, because these are easier to inspect. Check for excessive movement of the engine when revving the engine. You can also use a crowbar to test for excessive play.

If all engine and transmission mounts seem fine, you can try jacking up the vehicle and check if you can wiggle the wheels. If that's the case, the wheel bearings are most likely causing this issue.